# What is the "shell" window type in chrome extensions? Can it be used to hide a window?

Tags: shell, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, window

I just noticed this in the [trunk/dev](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/windows.html#type-Window) channel:

> ```
> type ( enumerated string ["normal", "popup", "panel", "app", "shell"] )
> ```
>
> The type of browser window this is.

I tried it with with Canary: no window is shown, but we have console output, so something has been created. The thing is I just don't get it. How is this different from a background page?

I was hoping to toggle windows completely out of the user's view, without having to reload the window's content when toggling up. Anyway, I'm not hoping much as you can't update a window type with chrome.windows.update. But the question still remains: what is this "shell" type?

Comment: more general question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672724/chrome-window-types-what-do-they-stand-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"shell" moved to the new [chrome.app.window](https://developer.chrome.com/beta/apps/app.window.html) API in [r140947](https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/10436015/diff/13004/chrome/common/extensions/api/windows.json). Then it appears to have disappeared from there in the [dev documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/dev/apps/app.window.html).

Answer (score 2):

"shell" currently does nothing for extensions and should not be used.

Comment: `[citation needed]` A statement without back-up is weak, unfortunately.