# Chrome window types. What do they stand for?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

chrome.windows API tells about 5 window types: "normal", "popup", "panel", "app", "shell".

- **Normal** windows are standard windows with tabs;
- **Popup** windows are 1) standalone windows with apps (this feature is currently available on Windows and Linux), 2) chrome devtools if its window is open separately;

But what are the other 3 window types? Official API provides [very little information](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#type-Window) about this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **App** used to be the application mode window (ran with `--app=http://...`) and is now replaced by popup type. Based on [this](http://code.google.com/codesearch#-jYZujsTozo/trunk/src/chrome/browser/browser.h) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium-os/issues/detail?id=20857).
- **Shell** I have my money on native system dialogs (Print using `Ctrl+Shift+P`) but can't really tell for sure.
- **Panel** are some snappy, buggy, always-on-top windows that dock near the tray area. You need to enable those with `--enable-panels` flag and they look like this on Windows:
- [image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about panel-type windows. They seem to be ugly.

Comment: Take a look at the Google plugin for chat.  The use of panels there is amazing: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Comment: But how to enable --enable-panels?

Comment: @Tom Start > Run > `%localappdata%/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --enable-panels` [Hit Enter]

Comment: and I guess panels are of fixed size

Comment: @LukeGT The link is 404

Comment: @BingLi224 lots have changed in 10 years. But there's now a rich notifications API available to Chrome Extensions which might help. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/richNotifications/